# How to generate unique alphanumeric in vb.net using visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to generate unique alphanumeric like A0B1C2D3,E4F5G6H7....
Currently i use random function. I think it has another way to generate it without using random function.

here is my code:

```
Function randLetter() As String
        Dim validchars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
        Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
        Return randomChar
    End Function

    Function randNumber() As String
        Dim validnum As String = "0123456789"
        Dim idx2 As Integer = rand.Next(0, validnum.Length)
        Dim randomChar2 As Char = validnum(idx2)
        Return randomChar2
    End Function

    Private Sub ButtonGnrte_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonGnrte.Click
        TextIDBox.Text = New String(randLetter() + randNumber() + randLetter() + randNumber() + randLetter() + randNumber() + randLetter() + randNumber())
    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You think wrong. Keep using a `Random` object. That said, exactly how you use the output generated by that `Random` object may not be optimal.  We can't know because you have failed to show us your actual code, which is ALWAYS a MUST when posting on SO.  If you have no code to post then you really aren't at the point of posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i already post my CODE.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a [GUID](https://guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx)?  Guid.NewGuid().ToString() will do that.

Comment: Random does not mean unique.  There is nothing there which will assure two series will be unique.  Depending on what this is for, you may want to hash something then encode it as Base26 or Base36